# "Factor codes of type double or float detected" when using read.dta13

Tags: r

I am using `read.dta13` packages to load data. There are a bunch of categorical variables with Stata values labels in the data set. The data set looks like below in Stata：

```
cohort year  age gender  income  health     migration
1101   2010  35    F      13034  healthy       yes
1102   2010  54    M      34134  unhealthy      no
```

For `gender`, `health` and `migration`, the original values are numeric, for example, `gender` = 1 for male. In Stata, for the convenience of understanding, I add value labels for categorical variables using `label define`, so it shows as above. But the original values are kept. Now let's go to R. If I simply type

```
mydata <- read.dta13("mydata_stata13.dta")
```

I get a lot of warnings like these

```
Factor codes of type double or float detected - no labels assigned.
Set option nonint.factors to TRUE to assign labels anyway.
```

All the value labels I add in Stata will be dropped, which is what I need in R. The problem is that R gives warnings even for some variables that should be taken as numeric, for example `income`. I don't want to set `nonint.factor = TRUE` since I need the numeric values of the categorical variables for the calculation.

It's not actually an error, but I would like to know whether it is safe to just ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning states, there are doubles or floats with labels assigned. This is because I assumed you created a categorical variable without specifying Stata to store it as a byte. `readstata13` gives you a warning because it is not sure if floats/doubles with value labels are categorical or continuous variables.

Let's say `gender` is the wrongly stored variable, I assumed the person who coded the variables in stata created it as:

```
gen gender = *expr*
```

instead of

```
gen byte gender = *expr*
```

This can be solved either by always prefixing categorical variables with `gen byte` or by using `compress` (see [Stata's manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dcompress.pdf)) before saving/exporting the whole dataset. You can detect which variables are wrongly coded using `describe` and checking value label assignment in non-byte-variables. This will in turn will store your data efficiently.

In addition, I assume that for some reason the same person accidentally added a value label to a "true" float variable, like `income` at some point. Check [labelbook command](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dlabelbook.pdf) to correct such problems.